# Why isn't telnet logging?

Tags: windows-10, logging, telnet

As you can see below I have specified a log file and logging is enabled.  You can see baretail opened in the background to the same file as the telnet logfile.  I then initiated a connection that fails.  Why is there no log data?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to get more specific...

Comment: Try setting the mode.  Try a different directory.

Comment: "FileName sets the file to be used for logging Telnet activity. The log file must be on your local computer."  If your E drive is a network drive, then it would fail the requirement, of being on your local computer.  If you need a network log file, I suggest, using a more versatile telnet application.

Comment: E:\ is a local drive.

Comment: Also the telnet session was a command prompt with administrative privileges.

Comment: Your screenshot says otherwise :$

Comment: You almost had me, but if you go through the steps once you issue the `open` command the title of the window changes.

Comment: proof: http://imgur.com/a/C6kDr

Answer (score 1):

> **logfile *FileName***  : Sets the file to be used for logging Telnet activity. The log file must be on your local computer. Logging begins automatically when you set this option.
>
> **logging**   : Turns on logging. If no log file is set, an error message appears.

I figured out that this is for logging active sessions.  It does not log connection errors.  It only starts logging on a successful connection.